# Passing variables from a php form through url hyperlinks

Tags: forms, variables, url, hyperlink

I am trying to pass variables from a php form onto a separate page, note that I do not have permission of the separate page. In another words, the form is a signup form that will have information that we want to pass onto another separate page to complete the signup process. Here's what I have:

```
<form id="contact-us" method="get" action="php/signup.php">
<div class="col-xs-12 animated" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="300">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" required="required" class="form light" placeholder="Sponsor's ID#    (leave it blank if you do not have one)" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="firstname" required="required" class="form light" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="lastname" required="required" class="form light" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" required="required" class="form light" placeholder="Email (optional)" />
<input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" required="required" class="form light" placeholder="Zipcode" />
</div>
<div class="relative fullwidth col-xs-12">
<a href="http://example.com/sample.asp?name=<?php echo $id?>&name=<?php echo $firstname?>&name=<?php echo $lastname?>&name=<?php echo $mail?>&name=<?php echo $zipcode?>"><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form-btn light">Join the Evolution</button></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

This is the php code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];    
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['mail'];
$zipcode = $_GET['zipcode'];

echo $id;
echo $firstname;
echo $lastname;
echo $email;
echo $zipcode;
```

This is the output I am getting:

`http://example.com/sample.asp?name=%3C?php%20echo%20$id?%3E&name=%3C?php%20echo%20$firstname?%3E&name=%3C?php%20echo%20$lastname?%3E&name=%20%3C?php%20echo%20$mail?%3E&name=%20%3C?php%20echo%20$zipcode?%3E`

I'm still learning, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably running your form from a .html file, and the PHP code isn't executing. As well, you've used the SAME `name` for multiple fields in the form, so even if PHP was working properly, the form wouldn't be submitting properly. `id` is irrelevant to form submissions. only the `name` and `value` attributes matter.

Comment: Noted. I will make the change on that. Thanks!